# Inner subclass of another inner class - how many refs to the root class?

Tags: java, subclass, inner-classes, memory-layout

Suppose I have the structure

```
class A {
    class B {}
    class C extends B {}
}
```

It seems that instances of `C` should have 2 references to the root class `A`: the first is inherited from `B` superclass, the second is own implicit inner class reference. My question: does JVM (HotSpot) optimize this case and keep only one reference to the root class?

Answer (score 0):

I decompiled A.class and got this result which shows two references to A, one from B and one from C. But this actually means that C actually has two references - one is its own and the other is inherited from B.

```
class A {

    class B {
        final A this$0;
        B() {
            this$0 = A.this;
        }
    }

    class C extends B {
        final A this$0;
        C() {
            this$0 = A.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JVM is not obligited to strictly follow byte code and waste space for 2 equal references indeed.